# Link section from specific library

Tags: gcc, ld

I have a GCC project for a microcontroller. There are some functions in the run-time that must be replaced to adapt the environment:

```
_write_r
_sbreak_r
```

I have implemented the functions in a file sys.c. When I link the file sys.o with my project it works as expected. But when I added the sys.o to a library bsp.a and link the library with my project the libc.a implementation gets precedence and my replacement doesn't work anymore.

How can I control the linker that it first links my library before it takes the definitions from the libc? I would prefer a solution where the linker script controls this precedence.

*Edit:* The GCC is called by the development environment for the linking stage. It controls the `ld` invokation and the `ld` command line parameters can't be controlled directly.

*Edit:* The CPU is a Cotex-M3 NXP LPC1788.

When I run the gcc linking command with the -v option I get this information:

```
c:/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/collect2.exe
--sysroot=arm\bin\../arm-none-eabi
-X
-o bin/test.elf
-n arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/armv7-m/crti.o arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/armv7-m/crtbegin.o arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m/crt0.o
-LD:/mylibs
-LC:\arm\lib
-Lc:/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/armv7-m
-Lc:/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m
-Lc:/arm/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m
-Lc:/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4
-Lc:/arm/bin/../lib/gcc
-Lc:/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib
-Lc:/arm/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib @C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9FN35g
--start-group -lgcc -lc --end-group
c:/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/armv7-m/crtend.o
c:/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/armv7-m/crtn.o
-T src\LPC1788_Flash.ld
```

Obviously there is a `--start-group -gcc -lc --end-group` argument to `collect2.exe`. But it has not been possible to add my library yet.

The file LPC1788_Flash.ld has this content:

```
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)
MEMORY {
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 512K
  RAM (xrw) : ORIGON = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
}
SECTIONS {
  // a lot of input and output sections, like ...
  .isr_vector : { . = ALIGN(4); KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) } >FLASH
  .data : { ... } >RAM
  .bss : { ... } >RAM
  /DISCARD/ : {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be harder than putting in them right order in linker invocation. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking/

Comment: @auselen This assumption is only true if you consider user libraries or if you invoke the linker manually. (please see my edit).

Comment: It is something can't be solvable by gcc's "-Wl" option? That switch passes options to linker.

Comment: Simply: I think you're libc binary is used only for the target arch? If so, you can simply remove the export in the libc and they won't overlap anymore.... (please notify @ me as I don't check for answers manually)

Comment: The libc is on several PCs and I won't modify it since the toolset that contains the libc is updated randomly.

Comment: @harper : I'm not talking about the libc of the PC used to build the binary for the micro-controller, I am talking of the libc binary built for the target system architecture not the Host.

Comment: @user2284570 I'm talking about the libc that is used for the target micro-controller. There is no libc for the host.

Comment: @harper : This the same for me: I never talked about the libc used on the host. This is was what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use the definitions of a source file of the custom library you have to make sure that the corresponding object file (of the library) is loaded before the system libraries are loaded to resolve externals.

This can be done by an explicit reference to a symbol of that file.

```
extern int _write_r();
void *magic = &_write_r;
```

This code should be placed so that the compiler will it not omit it due to optimization.

Using the linker script to build a group including the custom library with the system libraries is unfortunately not possible. The GROUP definitions of the linker script are processed after the groups defined by the built-in rules.

Comment: +1 Well, this is a run-time solution, but it can also work... :)

Comment: Nope it isn't run-time since there will nothing affected at run-time. But it's at source code level and requires pollution of the code and you get a `magic` variable what can add the confusion level. Additonal effort is required for comments to show why nobody should remove this hack. Therefore this is only in the category workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simply:
the glibc library itself face this problem: most function need to be linked statically but some can be used dynamically and used in a shared object.
Moreover, the static archive have the duplicate of some of the functions found in the Glibc shared object.

So on all the platforms were Glibc can be used as default, a linker script is installed with the static version of Glibc. Whatever the OS, the file is located under /lib/libc.so (or /lib64/libc.so if you are using 64-bits). It contains this:

```
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /lib64/libc.so.6 /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ) )
```

I don't know which libc you are using (it can be µClibc) but the file libc.so never lead to a binary (if it exist).

So, you need to either modify it or create it:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(the_format_used_by_your_micro-controller_architecture)
GROUP( /the_path_to_your_custom_library_binary /the_path_your_libc_binary AS_NEEDED ( /the path the_path_your_interpreter_binary ) )
```

The order in which you specify in the `GROUP()` matter: if the exports-symbols exists in both of the libraries binaries, then they will be provided by the first binary in the `GROUP()`.

Comment: When adding one or both lines 
OUTPUT_FORMART("elf32-littlearm")
GROUP ( d:/path/to/mylib.a d:/path/to/libc.a ) 
to the LD script I just get the message "syntax error" for the line with the first added line.

Comment: @harper : This mean elf32-littlearm is an invalid name (for gnu ld POV). I recognize finding the right name is hard. But you didn't told what is the processor your using. Remember there's several version of the ARM arch (arm5; arm7; arm12...) each one is incompatible with the others. You also used windows style of path (frive letter). Whatever the wrapper you're using, you need to understand you must use [UNIX style of path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_path#Unix_style "Wikipedia"). The root directory is relative to the root of your wrapper/development tools installation.

Comment: The objcopy acccepts exactly this argument:
`objcopy -I binary -O elf32-littlearm -B arm --rename-section .data=.rodata foo.png fpp\FatalError.o`
How can I lookup the valid name (for GNU ld POV)(or for COLLECT2 if this differ)?

Comment: You seriously asked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184558/symbol-collisions-with-libc-how-to-redirect-imported-symbol-to-a-particular-lib // Can't believe it.

Comment: @harper : It seems your's is off-topic in this case... :) May you tell me what is the processor your're using?

Comment: Would you please *read* the edits that I've done days before your comment?

Comment: @harper : there is no real way to find the arch name in a linker script : this is a very poor documentated part. I can't help you if you don't tell you CPU name. Anyway, you may try `ld --help | grep supported targets`. Also, may you specify you custom library path?

Comment: @harper : No. You told the brand but not the name nor the exact architecture version.

Comment: You asked for a processor instead of an exact architecture, didn't you?

Comment: @harper : Yes i'd like the exact name which is more precise (just to be sure). I can't tell you the `ld` name without the exact architecture.

Comment: The ld supports the architecture elf32-littlearm. The OUTPUT() statement in the linker script accepts elf32-littlearm. The output still runs on the target. So the exact architecture is elf32-littlearm. The GROUP statement in the linker script DOES NOT add the custom library to the group of libc,libgcc. Instead it creates a new group. That might be reason why this GROUP statement doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Nope, you commented the syntax error in the comment last week. But since the GROUP doesn't work at all your try of an answer doesn't help to solve the problem in question. Any order of the libs in the group doesn't help to link a section of a specific library.